# Bluetooth headphones keep disconnecting/reconnecting

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, pi-4

I have a pair of SoundbudSlim+ that I've been using for years on my phone. Trying to get them to work on the Pi4 running up to date Raspbian. I don't need the microphone, just the audio is fine. The Pi outputs audio through the 3.5mm jack fine; through the 3.5mm jack of the LCD I have on HDMI 0; and through the HDMI screen I also have connected to HDMI 1. I can see the SoundbudSlim+ just fine and pair them up without issues, but then no audio comes out and they keep disconnecting and immediately reconnecting (as verified in bluetoothctl).

if I info the device, it shows the right name and alias, indicates it's both paired and trusted, not blocked, and LegacyPairing: no. The Audio Sink service appears alongside a few others and has its own UUID.

sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service shows that every time it drops connection it registers: "Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)"

I've tried every step in this guide with no success: https://peppe8o.com/fixed-connect-bluet ... pberry-pi/
Anyone know what's going on here?

edit: here are some logs:

bluetoothctl

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: no
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: no
[DEL] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 SoundBuds Slim+
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller DC:A6:32:2D:90:B2 Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 SoundBuds Slim+
[NEW] Device 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13 USER-PC
[NEW] Device 50:AA:2B:33:26:77 50-AA-2B-33-26-77
[NEW] Device 7E:F6:66:44:7B:E1 7E-F6-66-44-7B-E1
[bluetooth]# pair E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31
Attempting to pair with E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 00000000-0000-0000-0099-aabbccddeeff
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: no
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 RSSI: -29
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: no
[bluetooth]# trust E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Trusted: yes
Changing E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# connect E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31
Attempting to connect to E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: yes
Connection successful
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 ServicesResolved: yes
[SoundBuds Slim+]# info E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31
Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 (public)
    Name: SoundBuds Slim+
    Alias: SoundBuds Slim+
    Class: 0x00240404
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00000000-0000-0000-0099-aabbccddeeff)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    RSSI: -29
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: no
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 00000000-0000-0000-0099-aabbccddeeff
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: no
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: no
[CHG] Device E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 Connected: yes
```

systemctl

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-03-23 17:44:56 CET; 16h ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 721 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 2.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─721 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap

Mar 24 10:03:52 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Mar 24 10:07:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Authentication attempt without agent
Mar 24 10:07:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Access denied: org.bluez.Error.Rejected
Mar 24 10:07:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Authentication attempt without agent
Mar 24 10:07:19 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Hands-Free Voice gateway rejected E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31: org.bluez.Error.Rejected
Mar 24 10:08:23 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Mar 24 10:08:53 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Mar 24 10:09:40 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Mar 24 10:10:29 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Mar 24 10:11:00 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
```

syslog:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ tail -f /var/log/syslog
Mar 24 10:08:55 raspberrypi bluealsa[731]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Unsupported AT message: SET: command:+CLIP, value:1
Mar 24 10:08:55 raspberrypi bluealsa[731]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Unsupported AT message: SET: command:+XEVENT, value:AB-12-0100,1
Mar 24 10:08:56 raspberrypi kernel: [  970.603525] input: E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 as /devices/virtual/input/input10
Mar 24 10:08:56 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[2015]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
Mar 24 10:09:40 raspberrypi bluetoothd[721]: Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Mar 24 10:09:43 raspberrypi bluealsa[731]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Unsupported AT message: SET: command:+CSCS, value:"UTF-8"
Mar 24 10:09:43 raspberrypi bluealsa[731]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Unsupported AT message: SET: command:+CLIP, value:1
Mar 24 10:09:43 raspberrypi bluealsa[731]: /usr/bin/bluealsa: Unsupported AT message: SET: command:+XEVENT, value:AB-12-0100,1
Mar 24 10:09:44 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1018.223137] input: E8:07:BF:6C:6A:31 as /devices/virtual/input/input11
Mar 24 10:09:44 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[2223]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
```